# How to make multi columns with different rows for each columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am currently blocked because I would like to make a `CSV` file with my first columns to be filled only with keys and my second columns to be filled with my values and the headers. Like this :
[image: Screenshot 1]

but actually look like this :
[image: Screenshot 2]

My JSON test file :

```
{
 "name":"<customer>_<datetime>.zip",
 "status":"OK",
 "lib_status":"SUCCESS",
 "ID":" ",
 "ID_emitter":"<customer>",
 "recipient":" ",
 "validator":{
     "sender_email_address":"example@example.com",
     "sender_email_address_no_reply":"example@example.com"
     },
 "connexFileList":[
   {
        "connexFile":"<customer>_<datetime>",
        "type":"json"
   }
   ],
  "PReS":{
    "domain":" ",
    "client":" ",
    "inputFlowList":[
        {
            "inputFile":" ",
            "type":" ",
            "status":" "
        }
        ]
    }
   }
```

my current code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('test.json') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)

name = json_dict['name']
status = json_dict['status']
lib_status = json_dict['lib_status']
ID_emitter = json_dict['ID_emitter']

for connexFileList in json_dict['connexFileList']:
    connexFile = connexFileList['connexFile'],
    type2 = connexFileList['type']

for PReS in json_dict['PReS']['inputFlowList']:
    inputFile = PReS['inputFile']
    type3 = PReS['type']
    status2 = PReS['status']

raw_data = {
"firstitem": [name, status, lib_status, ID_emitter, '', '', '', '', ''],
"connexFileList": ['', '', '', '', connexFile, type2, '', '', ''],
"PReS": ['','','','','','', inputFile, type3, status2],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
              index=pd.Index(['name :', 'status :', 'lib_status', 'ID_emitter', 
                              'connexFile','type','inputFile', 'type', 'status']),
              columns=pd.Index(['firstitem', 'connexFileList', 'PReS'])
              )
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=";")
```

But this is not what I want for my `CSV`, and the raw_data with `[' ', ' ',...]` it's not really optimized...
I think the solution is `pd.MultiIndex` or `pd.Series` but I don't know how applied these two solutions in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
raw_data = {
 "firstitem": [name, status, lib_status, ID_emitter, '', '', '', '', ''],
 " ": ['connexFile','type','', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
 "connexFileList": [connexFile, type2, '', '', '','', '', '', ''],
 "PReS": ['','','','','','', inputFile, type3, status2],
"": ['inputFile','type','status', '', '', '', '', '', '']
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,
           index=pd.Index(['name', 'status', 'lib_status', 'ID_emitter', 
                           '','','', '', '']),
           columns=pd.Index(['firstitem', ' ','connexFileList','', 'PReS'])
           )
```

Comment: That's exactelly what I wanted ! Thank you, but do you have any idea for optimize the raw_data, principally these list `[' ', ' ', ' ',...]` ?

Comment: @PunkyLama I'm glad that it solved your issue.. if you want you can mark the solution as accepted. let me check if i can help in optimizing